# Where is Ptah in the PF2e pantheon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, religions-and-deities, pathfinder-2e

I'm a bit confused. https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx doesn't list Ptah, but the first edition PRD does: https://aonprd.com/DeityDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ptah.

Does anyone know what happened to Ptah between editions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one has said anything about Ptah in 2e, but odds are nothing has happened at all. He just hasn't been mentioned because he is a deity that is rarely discussed.

### No one has said

As you noted, Ptah has not yet made an appearance in Pathfinder 2e. I also searched the Paizo forums and my own notes for Pathfinder Society-related plot information, and found nothing. So it seems like no one has said anything that would answer your question.

### But probably nothing has changed

Ptah was introduced in a Pathfinder module, not in any core rulebook or setting information. The [PathfinderWiki article for Ptah](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Ptah) similarly only attributes Ptah to this one book, [*Pathfinder Adventure Path #80: Empty Graves*](https://paizo.com/products/btpy94vv?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-80-Empty-Graves) - an adventure which is a part of the *Mummy's Mask* adventure path. With that level of "support", it's probably not reasonable to expect him to be included at all, let alone a product with a relatively short run (so far).

Similarly, not much has changed in the world of Golarion between 1e and 2e.  In general, the major change is that the content of the adventure paths is now factual (recent) history. So odds are nothing happened to Ptah at all.

Comment: A pedantic point...Empty Graves is part of a Pathfinder Adventure Path. It's neither a Module, nor part of Pathfinder Society. Also...the part of the book Ptah was discussed in is, in fact, setting material.

Comment: @YogoZuno I updated this to reflect that Empty Graves is a part of an adventure path. With regards to setting information, I'm trying to distinguish between products like the Inner Sea World Guide (which Paizo includes in their catalogue as 'campaign setting' products) and the relatively ephemeral information that sporadically appears in others (like Adventure Paths).

Comment: I understand, although many other setting details, such as the identities and portfolios of Demon Lords, were first published in an AP before appearing in splat books.

Answer (score 1):

Worship of Ptah was added to Pathfinder along with many other Ancient Osirion (aka Egyptian) gods as part of the Empty Graves chapter of the Mummy's Mask Adventure Path (which was very focused on Osirion). A number of the other gods from that article ARE present in the 2nd ed list of Deities, but certainly not all. Apep and Set for instance are missing. Similarly, a number of other divine beings from various sources are not present in the list, such as the Demon Lords Deskari and Orcus.

Some of the changes in the list from 1st edition represent background changes, such as the lack of entry for [Deskari](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Deskari), and changes in status of [Nocticula](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Nocticula). However, other changes or omissions are likely just things that have not yet been looked at in detail in 2nd edition books, and may be visited in the future.

In the case of Ptah, I expect that very little has changed. The Ancient Osirion pantheon was noted in the original Empty Graves article as having been actively suppressed during the Keleshite Interregnum, and so likely does not have a large number of followers.